# $.ajax not working in mvc4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Please refer below code

```
var pdf="xxxxxxx";

 $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Corporate/SampleChangeSummary/PDF",
            data: JSON.stringify(pdf),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (status, xhr) {

            }
        });


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PDF(object pdf)
        {
.......
}
```

but it returning **pdf is null**. What is the problem? Any syntax mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `contentType` is what causing the issue.  In that script of yours, you were telling your `$.ajax()` that it is sending JSON string, but you had it sending a .pdf.  Instead, just remove `contentType` line and try it.

Secondly, `dataType: 'json'` is telling your `$.ajax()` that it is expecting the response in JSON format.  If that's what you are doing, then you dont have to worry about that line.

EDITED:

Found more information - if you wanted to keep `contentType` then, revise to this: `contentType: application/pdf',` and add `header('Content-type: application/pdf');` on your php file that your `$.ajax()` is sending to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/Corporate/SampleChangeSummary/PDF",
    data: JSON.stringify({pdf: pdf}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (status, xhr) { }
});
```

ASP.NET MVC requires you to send a 'key-value' JSON object so it can bind accordingly. Also, change `object pdf` to `string pdf`.

Comment: Also, try it:
`contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf8'`

Comment: If this is not working, then you're doing something really weird there.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/Corporate/SampleChangeSummary/PDF',
         data: { pdf: JSON.stringify(pdf) },
         success: function (data) {
                    //do somthing with the result
                  },
         error: function (error) {
                    alert('Please try again!');
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var pdf="xxxxxxx";

   $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/Corporate/SampleChangeSummary/PDF",
        data: { "pdf" : pdf },
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (status, xhr) {

        }
    });


  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PDF(object pdf)
    {
       .......
    }
```

you don't need to stringify your pdf because it is already string try to pass it directly to your controller.